# Cannot hit breakpoint while making network request

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

Debuggers break-point does not hit when I do network request, even though network request is sent.

1. Calling from ViewModel

Here:

```
fun getData(): Single<ArrayList<Data>> {
    return service.getData()
        .map { jsonApiObject ->
            val x: ArrayList<Data> = ArrayList() /*Breakpoint is here*/
            return@map x
        }
}
```

Well, the break-point should hit whenever I call this function, but it does not. When I log request with interceptor, I can see that the request link is correct and response code is 200 with correct data. What could cause this? I tried to rebuild project/invalidate cache.

Even if I had wrong gson converter configuration set up with retrofit2, theoretically I still should get till the break point and only when using gson builder object, only then get an error, right?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

**FOUND THE REASON:**

Whenever I `.addConverterFactory(
            JSONConverterFactory.create(...::class.java))` debugger will stop inside map block, but if I do `.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())` it will not. Why?

Comment: why `jsonApiObject` and `users` are underlined in zigzag ??

Comment: @MartinZeitler Because they're not used. :)

Comment: try setting a break-point at `return` and one inside `usersService.getUsers()` ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler Found the reason - check at the end of post. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `Debug.waitForDebugger()` before the line where you want to have the breakpoint.

Comment: can you write some println statement inside map block and see if it gets printed.

Comment: Found the reason - check at the end of post. Any ideas why?